# Why is the run method two times called before updating when using handler.postDelayed

Tags: java, android, runnable, android-handler

I have a general problem understanding how the `run` method is called when using `handler.postDelayed` in Android.

I have the following Java code:

```
public class Test extends Fragment implements Runnable {

    public static final int DELAY_IN_MILLIS = 10;
    private int currentTimeLeft_MILLIS;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    int helpCounterRun =0;

    private boolean viewHasBeenCreated = false;
    private FragmentTestBinding binding;

    public Test() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        currentTimeLeft_MILLIS = 90 * 1000;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentTestBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        viewHasBeenCreated = true;
        getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        countDownTime();
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    private void updateScreen() {
        binding.textViewTimeLeftValue.setText("" + currentTimeLeft_MILLIS/1000);
        Log.e("LogTag", "Method updateScreen" );
    }

    private void countDownTime(){
        currentTimeLeftInTheLevel_MILLIS = currentTimeLeftInTheLevel_MILLIS - DELAY_IN_MILLIS;
        Log.e("LogTag", "Method countDownTime - currentTimeLeftInTheLevel_MILLIS: " + currentTimeLeftInTheLevel_MILLIS);

        handler.postDelayed(this, DELAY_IN_MILLIS);
        updateScreen();
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        helpCounterRun++;
        Log.e("LogTag", "Method run - helpCounterRun: " + helpCounterRun);
        if(viewHasBeenCreated) {
            countDownTime();
        }

    }
}
```

Next to the `onCreate` and `onCreateView` method this Fragment has 3 basic methods. The `updateScreen()` method should update the `currentTimeLeft_MILLIS` in a textview. So it should actually display the remaining time in seconds (starting from 90 seconds). The method `countDownTime()` should just decrease the variable `currentTimeLeft_MILLIS` by `DELAY_IN_MILLIS` call the method `updateScreen()` and it used the call `handler.postDelayed(this, DELAY_IN_MILLIS);` to call the Runnable `run()` which calls the `countDownTime()`method again.

When I look at the `LogTag`outputs it looks like this

```
2022-03-11 17:59:30.128 7361-7361/com.example.game E/LogTag: Method run - helpCounterRun: 1
2022-03-11 17:59:30.128 7361-7361/com.example.game E/LogTag: Method countDownTime - currentTimeLeft_MILLIS: 89980
2022-03-11 17:59:30.135 7361-7361/com.example.game E/LogTag: Method updateScreen
2022-03-11 17:59:31.918 7361-7361/com.example.game E/LogTag: Method run - helpCounterRun: 1
2022-03-11 17:59:31.919 7361-7361/com.example.game E/LogTag: Method countDownTime - currentTimeLeft_MILLIS: 89980
2022-03-11 17:59:31.919 7361-7361/com.example.game E/LogTag: Method updateScreen
2022-03-11 17:59:31.924 7361-7361/com.example.game E/LogTag: Method run - helpCounterRun: 2
2022-03-11 17:59:31.925 7361-7361/com.example.game E/LogTag: Method countDownTime - currentTimeLeft_MILLIS: 89970
2022-03-11 17:59:31.925 7361-7361/com.example.game E/LogTag: Method updateScreen
2022-03-11 17:59:32.028 7361-7361/com.example.game E/LogTag: Method run - helpCounterRun: 2
2022-03-11 17:59:32.029 7361-7361/com.example.game E/LogTag: Method countDownTime - currentTimeLeft_MILLIS: 89970
2022-03-11 17:59:32.029 7361-7361/com.example.game E/LogTag: Method updateScreen
2022-03-11 17:59:32.029 7361-7361/com.example.game E/LogTag: Method run - helpCounterRun: 3
2022-03-11 17:59:32.029 7361-7361/com.example.game E/LogTag: Method countDownTime - currentTimeLeft_MILLIS: 89960
2022-03-11 17:59:32.030 7361-7361/com.example.game E/LogTag: Method updateScreen
2022-03-11 17:59:32.089 7361-7361/com.example.game E/LogTag: Method run - helpCounterRun: 3
2022-03-11 17:59:32.089 7361-7361/com.example.game E/LogTag: Method countDownTime - currentTimeLeft_MILLIS: 89960
```

What I don't understand is why the run method is called two times before it updates `helpCounterRun++;`. So I can see that the code "visits" the `run()` method one time in which it does not update the variable `helpCounterRun++;` ? Also the other methods do every thing two times before updating and I don't understand why. Do I start 2 separate threads with this code?

Another problem (that might be realted to the first problem) is that the countdown that the textView displays is too slow. It should decrease the value by 1 every second (by decreasing the value of `currentTimeLeftInTheLevel_MILLIS` after `DELAY_IN_MILLIS`).

Do you have any idea why these 2 problems occur?

**Update**: When use `this`before printing the strings in the LogTag in `Log.e("LogTag", "Method countDownTime - this: " + this);` and         `Log.e("LogTag", "Method run - this: " + this);`

I get a slightly different output:

```
2022-03-13 09:37:54.693 9512-9512/com.example.game E/LogTag: Method run - helpCounterRun: 1
2022-03-13 09:37:54.693 9512-9512/com.example.game E/LogTag: Method run - this: Test{1f79232} (ad58656d-a106-4ab6-8d65-8ee20d095fbf)}
2022-03-13 09:37:54.693 9512-9512/com.example.game E/LogTag: Method countDownTime - currentTimeLeft_MILLIS: 89980
2022-03-13 09:37:54.694 9512-9512/com.example.game E/LogTag: Method countDownTime - this: Test{1f79232} (ad58656d-a106-4ab6-8d65-8ee20d095fbf)}
2022-03-13 09:37:54.694 9512-9512/com.example.game E/LogTag: Method updateScreen
2022-03-13 09:37:54.696 9512-9512/com.example.game E/LogTag: Method updateScreen - this: Test{1f79232} (ad58656d-a106-4ab6-8d65-8ee20d095fbf)}
2022-03-13 09:37:55.991 9512-9512/com.example.game E/LogTag: Method run - helpCounterRun: 1
2022-03-13 09:37:55.991 9512-9512/com.example.game E/LogTag: Method run - this: Test{1cbc30c} (6c4409c6-c501-4b40-9e33-cbf1895c68f6) id=0x7f08013c}
2022-03-13 09:37:55.992 9512-9512/com.example.game E/LogTag: Method countDownTime - currentTimeLeft_MILLIS: 89980
2022-03-13 09:37:55.992 9512-9512/com.example.game E/LogTag: Method countDownTime - this: Test{1cbc30c} (6c4409c6-c501-4b40-9e33-cbf1895c68f6) id=0x7f08013c}
2022-03-13 09:37:55.993 9512-9512/com.example.game E/LogTag: Method updateScreen
2022-03-13 09:37:55.993 9512-9512/com.example.game E/LogTag: Method updateScreen - this: Test{1cbc30c} (6c4409c6-c501-4b40-9e33-cbf1895c68f6) id=0x7f08013c}
2022-03-13 09:37:56.009 9512-9512/com.example.game E/LogTag: Method run - helpCounterRun: 2
2022-03-13 09:37:56.010 9512-9512/com.example.game E/LogTag: Method run - this: Test{1f79232} (ad58656d-a106-4ab6-8d65-8ee20d095fbf)}
2022-03-13 09:37:56.010 9512-9512/com.example.game E/LogTag: Method countDownTime - currentTimeLeft_MILLIS: 89970
2022-03-13 09:37:56.010 9512-9512/com.example.game E/LogTag: Method countDownTime - this: Test{1f79232} (ad58656d-a106-4ab6-8d65-8ee20d095fbf)}
2022-03-13 09:37:56.020 9512-9512/com.example.game E/LogTag: Method updateScreen
2022-03-13 09:37:56.021 9512-9512/com.example.game E/LogTag: Method updateScreen - this: Test{1f79232} (ad58656d-a106-4ab6-8d65-8ee20d095fbf)}
2022-03-13 09:37:56.121 9512-9512/com.example.game E/LogTag: Method run - helpCounterRun: 2
2022-03-13 09:37:56.122 9512-9512/com.example.game E/LogTag: Method run - this: Test{1cbc30c} (6c4409c6-c501-4b40-9e33-cbf1895c68f6) id=0x7f08013c}
2022-03-13 09:37:56.122 9512-9512/com.example.game E/LogTag: Method countDownTime - currentTimeLeft_MILLIS: 89970
2022-03-13 09:37:56.122 9512-9512/com.example.game E/LogTag: Method countDownTime - this: Test{1cbc30c} (6c4409c6-c501-4b40-9e33-cbf1895c68f6) id=0x7f08013c}
2022-03-13 09:37:56.124 9512-9512/com.example.game E/LogTag: Method updateScreen
2022-03-13 09:37:56.125 9512-9512/com.example.game E/LogTag: Method updateScreen - this: Test{1cbc30c} (6c4409c6-c501-4b40-9e33-cbf1895c68f6) id=0x7f08013c}
```

**Update 2**: I was asked to show the code that launches the problematic fragment `Test`. Here you can see the Fragment `FR_Menu` that launches the fragment `Test`after clicking on the corresponding button.

```
public class FR_Menu extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    private FragmentMenuBinding binding;
    

    public FR_Menu() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentMenuBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        binding.buttonGame.setOnClickListener(this);
        binding.buttonOptions.setOnClickListener(this);
        binding.buttonHighscores.setOnClickListener(this);
        binding.buttonFacts.setOnClickListener(this);
        binding.buttonExit.setOnClickListener(this);
        binding.buttonTest.setOnClickListener(this);
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if(view.getId() == R.id.button_game) {
            
            Navigation.findNavController(getView()).navigate(FR_MenuDirections.actionFRMenuToFRGame());
        }

        if(view.getId() == R.id.button_highscores) {
            Navigation.findNavController(getView()).navigate(FR_MenuDirections.actionFRMenuToFRHighScores());
        }

        if(view.getId() == R.id.button_facts) {
            Navigation.findNavController(getView()).navigate(FR_MenuDirections.actionFRMenuToFRInterestingFacts());
        }

        if(view.getId() == R.id.button_options) {
            Navigation.findNavController(getView()).navigate(FR_MenuDirections.actionFRMenuToFROptions());
        }
//This launches the problematic Fragment "Test"
        if(view.getId() == R.id.button_test) {
            Navigation.findNavController(getView()).navigate(FR_MenuDirections.actionFRMenuToTest());
        }

        if(view.getId() == R.id.button_exit) {
            getActivity().finishAndRemoveTask();
        }
        
    }
}
```

**Reminder**: Does nobody have any idea?

Comment: Making a Fragment a Runnable is super weird.  Generally you'd create an annonymous class and use that for a runnable.

Comment: Also, are you sure you have only one instance of the fragment?  Printing out this to make sure its the same instance might help.

Comment: @GabeSechan:´Thanks for your comments. I make the Fragment a Runnable because this is acutally a game with UI elements being changed all the time in the Fragment. Regarding you second question I don't know how to print the needed information out. I use a One Activity Multiple Fragments approach and I just start this Fragment once.

Comment: ITs still weird and a bad idea to make you fragment implement runnable.  Use an annonymous class inside the fragment instead, it will make your code much clearer.  As for printing the instance-  literally add "this" to the string you're printing

Comment: @GabeSechan: Thanks for your answer. I added `this` before printing and received a slightly different output (see my Update). Can you infer something out of this? Furhter, I don't understand your advice with the anonymous inside class. Where exactly and how shall I add it? After `handler.postDelayed()`

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood.  Not this.helpCounterRun.  Just this.  I want it to print out the reference id of the class, because I think 2 instances exist and are running.

Comment: @GabeSechan: Thanks Gabe for your comment. I know changed the code and the output. It seems that there are in fact 2 instances being started but the big question is why and where are those two instances started?In my code I only use `handler.postDelayed(this, DELAY_IN_MILLIS);` once and I don't understand why this starts 2 runnables at the same time.

Comment: If there's 2 instances you don't have 2 runnables, you have 2 fragments (since your runnable is a fragment).  We'd need to see the code creating/launching this fragment to help

Comment: @GabeSechan: Thanks Gabe for your answer and effort. I updated my question (Update 2) and posted the code of the Fragment that launches the problematic Fragment. Can you infer something out of it that explains, why 2 runnables are started?

Comment: @GabeSechan: Any comments to my last comments? I'll highly appreciate every further comment from you